# Code not working issues with if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is having issues, it is suppose to print either "You have a rare surname!" or a very rare one if you have q or Q in the typed string And if not it will print no q's, but it does not print no q's.

Here my not working code:

```
a = input("What is your surname? ")
d = len(a)
v = ["q", "Q"]
if any(v in a for v in a):
  if a[0] == "Q" :
    if a[0] == ("q"):
      print("You have an extremly rare surname!")
    if a[0] == ("Q"):
      print("You have an extremly rare surname!")
  if a[0] == "q" :
    if a[0] == ("q"):
      print("You have an extremly rare surname!")
    if a[0] == ("Q"):
      print("You have an extremly rare surname!")
  if "q" in a[1:d]:
    print("You have a rare surname!")
else:
  print("No Qs here.")
```

Comment: You forgot the picture - but don't bother adding it. Instead please add your actual code.

Comment: If we can't copy-paste your code to test it we can't really help most of the time, edit your question and paste your code here (not in a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition `if any(v in a for v in a)` makes no sense, you are testing if `v` is in `a` but at the same time defining `v` as part of `a`, it makes no sense.

Also, your other conditions are pretty bad too, you test if the first letter is `Q` and then if that's true you test if it's actually `q`.

Your entire program can be written as

```
a = input("what is your surname?")
if a[0] in ('q', 'Q'):
    print('extremely rare')
elif 'q' in a[1:] or 'Q' in a[1:]:
    print('rare')
else:
    print('no q here')
```

If you do not understand any of the conditions that I used I highly recommend you go back and relearn basic python syntax for conditions so you can write it better next time

Answer (score 0):

Another way to simplify your code would would be to just use [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to convert the string to lowercase and use a string [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to check the string without the first character:

```
rare_letter = 'q'
user_surname = input("What is your surname? ").lower()

if user_surname[0] == rare_letter:
  print("You have an extremly rare surname!")
elif rare_letter in user_surname[1:]:
  print("You have a rare surname!")
else:
  print("No Qs here.")
```

Try it out [here!](https://repl.it/Jyex/1)